# What is the meaning of "I'm about"?

Tags: meaning

I often come across this phrase and don't fully understand its meaning. I will be glad to find out at last. Here is the example https://youtu.be/aELb5Smu14U?t=219 3:39

> I'm doing all the stuff they told black people in middle school I [sic] couldn't do.  I'm going to therapy - it's great.  Eating blueberries - they're delicious.  Haven't been skiing - still think it's dangerous.  And um...
>
> No, I do like it.  I like knowing what **I'm about**, you know?  I'm trying to figure out who I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What you are about" is an informal expression that means "who you are". So this quote means, "*I like knowing who I am*".

Comment: thanks, I know this guestion was silly but I couldn't find an answer in russian translate apps. I've heard how this construction is used to express intent to do smth yet this is not that case

Comment: It's so informal that I'm not surprised translators don't catch it. It's a good question